# D3 Reusable Chart Function Creating Multiple Charts

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I've built a reusable chart function (hat tip to Mike Bostock - http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/):

```
function chartBubble() {
  var width = 800,
      height = 800; 

  function chart() {
   var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height); 

   // generate rest of chart here
  }

  chart.width = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return width;
    width = value;
    return chart;
  };

  return chart;
}
```

This works great initialy by calling the function:

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function (data) {
 d3.select("#chart")
  .datum(data)
  .call(chartBubble().width(800));
});
```

The problem, which creates a duplicate svg chart object, arises when I want to change the width by calling:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
  d3.select("#chart")
   .call(chartBubble().width(500)); 
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would change the implementation to be *more* reusable:

```js
function chartBubble() {
  var width = 800,
      height = 800; 

  function chart(selection) {
    selection.each(function (d, i) {
        var chartElem = d3.select(this);
        var svg = chartElem.selectAll('svg').data([d]);

        var svgEnter = svg.enter().append('svg');

        // Now append the elements which need to be inserted
        // only once to svgEnter.
        // e.g. 'g' which contains axis, title, etc.

        // 'Update' the rest of the graph here.
        // e.g. set the width/height attributes which change:
        svg
           .attr('width', width)
           .attr('height', height);

    });
  }

  chart.width = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return width;
    width = value;
    return chart;
  };

  return chart;
}
```

Then you would create the chart in much the same way:

```
// Bubble is created separately and is initialized
var bubble = chartBubble().width(800);

d3.csv("data.csv", function (data) {
 d3.select("#chart")
  .datum(data)
  .call(bubble);
});
```

Then when it comes to *updating* the chart either by updating the `data` or by changing other attributes, you have a uniform way of doing it, very close to your implementation:

```js
$("#button").click(function(){
  // The advantage of defining bubble is that we can now change only
  // width while preserving other attributes.
  bubble.width(500);
  d3.select("#chart")
  //.datum(newData)
    .call(bubble); 
});
```

Comment: In trying to append g to svgEnter I am getting "svgEnter.selectAll is not a function" when using it in this context: `force.nodes(d);

            node = svgEnter.selectAll(".node")
                .data(d)
                .enter().append("g")`

Comment: Have you appended an `svg` element already, i.e. `svgEnter.append('svg')`? Otherwise, I will need more context than that to be able to debug it. Can you create a minimal jsFiddle for it?

Comment: `var svgEnter = svg.enter().append('svg');`. Fixed in the code: http://jsfiddle.net/bMjJm/ and in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's a framework out there now which can create reusable d3 charts (based on Mike Bostock's article - http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/):

[d3.chart](http://misoproject.com/d3-chart/)

An extensive article on this - http://weblog.bocoup.com/reusability-with-d3/ and http://weblog.bocoup.com/introducing-d3-chart/